# ssmtp - Mail command not found

Tags: email, ssmtp

I've installed ssmtp and I can send emails fine using the ssmtp command.
However the mail command doesn't work.
How do I set this up?

Comment: You don't say which distribution or version of Linux, UNIX or anything else you're using.  So doing that would be useful.  ssmtp for example could be running under Cygwin and the answer will be totally different if it's running under Debian, or SLES, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `mail` is usually provided by the `mailx` package.

> License     : BSD with advertising and MPLv1.1 Description : Mailx is
>   an enhanced mail command, which provides the functionality
>               : of the POSIX mailx command, as well as SysV mail and Berkeley Mail
>               : (from which it is derived).

Answer (score 5):

In case you're using Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Red Hat / CentOS: `sudo yum -y install mailx`